# Reverse for 'str_team' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['str_application\\-1/(?P<startup_id>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

i have two models, one is startup where the startup name is created and second is team where dynamically extra team members are created. the process goes in steps and when the startup name is created and redirected to second step i get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'str_team' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['str_application\\-1/(?P<startup_id>[^/]+)/$']
```

as far i was reading, a template tag must be added in order to pass instances from one template to another through URL. appreciate your help, below is my code:
**URLS**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path ( 'str_dashboard/' , views.str_dashboard , name = 'str_dashboard' ) ,
    path ( 'str_application/' , views.startup, name = 'str_name' ) ,
    path ( 'str_application-1/<int:startup_id>/' , views.startup, name = 'str_team' ) ,
]
```

**Models**:

```
from django.db import models


class Startup ( models.Model ) :
    startup_name = models.CharField ( 'Startup Name' , max_length = 100 )

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.startup_name


class Team ( models.Model ) :
    name = models.CharField ( 'Name' , max_length = 100 )
    position = models.CharField ( 'Position' , max_length = 100 )
    startup = models.ForeignKey ( Startup , on_delete = models.CASCADE )

    def __str__(self) :
        return str(self.startup)

class Req_Fund(models.Model):
    startup_2 = models.ForeignKey ( Startup , on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    funds = models.DecimalField ( 'Requested Fund' , max_digits = 14 , decimal_places = 2 , null = False , blank = False )
    product_development = models.DecimalField ( 'Product Development' ,max_digits = 14 , decimal_places = 2 , null = False , blank = False)
    marketing_sales = models.DecimalField ( 'Marketing/Sales' , max_digits = 14 , decimal_places = 2 , null = False , blank = False)
    operation_inventory = models.DecimalField ( 'Operations/Inventory' , max_digits = 14 , decimal_places = 2 , null = False , blank = False)
    legal_other = models.DecimalField ( 'Legal/Others' ,max_digits = 14 , decimal_places = 2 , null = False , blank = False)

    def __str__(self) :
        return str(self.startup_2)
```

**FORMS**:

```
from .models import *
from django import forms

class StartupNameForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Startup
        fields = ['startup_name',]

class TeamForm (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ['startup','name','position',]
        widgets = { 'startup' : forms.HiddenInput ( ) }

class ReqFund (forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Req_Fund
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = { 'startup_2' : forms.HiddenInput ( ) }
```

**VIEWS**:

```
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .decorators import str_required
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect
from .forms import *
from .models import *

@login_required ( login_url = 'str_login' )
@str_required
def str_dashboard(request) :
    return render ( request , 'str_dashboard.html' )


def startup(request ):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StartupNameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('str_team')
    else:
        form = StartupNameForm()
        return render(request, 'application/str_name.html', {'form': form})


def team(request, startup_id):
    startup = Startup.objects.get(id=startup_id)
    TeamFormset = inlineformset_factory(Startup, Team, fields = ('name', 'position', 'startup'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TeamFormset(request.POST, instance = startup)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()

        return redirect ('str_dashboard')

    formset = TeamFormset ( instance = startup )
    return render ( request , 'application/str_team.html' , { 'formset' : formset } )


def reqfund (request, startup_id):
    strup = Startup.objects.get(id=startup_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReqFund(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            i = form.save (commit = False)
            i.startup.id = strup.id
            i.save()
        return redirect('str_dashboard')
    else:
        form = ReqFund()
        return render(request, 'application/str_rfund.html', {'form': form})
```

**HTML TEMPLATE - for statup Name**:

```
<form method='post' href="{url 'str_name' startup_id}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**HTML TEMPLATE - for team**:

```
<form id="my-form" method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.media }}
    <div class="individual-form">
        {{ formset|crispy }}
    </div>

    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Error trace back**:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\untitled1\sourcing\startups\views.py" in startup
  20.             return redirect('str_team')

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in redirect
  58.     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in resolve_url
  148.         return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\Lenovo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  622.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /str_application/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'str_team' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['str\\-application\\-1/(?P<startup_id>[0-9]+)$']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the primary key as parameter to the URL, like:

```
def startup(request ):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StartupNameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            result = form.save()
            return redirect('str_team', startup_id=result.pk)
    else:
        form = StartupNameForm()
    return render(request, 'application/str_name.html', {'form': form})
```

Note that you should perform a `return render(..)` in both the `if` case (if the form was not valid) and the `else` case (if it is a GET request).

Furthermore there is a second problem that your `__str__` of the `Team` does *not* return a `str`ing, it returns a `Startup`:

```
class Team(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField ('Name', max_length =100)
    position = models.CharField ('Position', max_length=100)
    startup = models.ForeignKey (Startup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self) :
        return str(self.startup)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198525/discussion-on-answer-by-willem-van-onsem-reverse-for-str-team-with-no-argument).

Comment: @Willwm Van Onsem: i have updated the question to reflect the part am doing however, the third form is not saving to database

Answer (score 1):

The third URL path is written wrongly.
It should be written like this.

```py
path('str-application-1/<int:startup_id>',...)
```